# Reload spreadsheet in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

We have a spreadsheet on a shared drive that one person updates and the rest of use just read. I was pretty sure that when we used Excel 2003, if the author updated the spreadsheet, Excel would notify the user and reload. Excel 2010 doesn't seem to be doing that, at least not automatically, so the author sends an email telling me about the changes, and then I have to close the file an re-open it. Is there a button somewhere which will just reload the file in a single click, or even better, automatically detect the changes and display them (the file is locked to me, I can only read it so I am not worried about losing changes)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may depend on what shared file store you are using.

Certainly 2010 does do what you have suggested happened for 2003. If one person has the file open, the second is told that it is open and offered read-only. They should also be offered that they are notified when the original user closes the file. When that happens, Excel offers to reload the file in read-write mode.

However, it may not always work. I've often seen it fail to do any or some of those things and that is on a Windows network share. Using older versions of Windows server or Linux SAMBA servers may have more impact. Having a slow or unreliable network will certainly impact it. You might also find that the lock is never released, we see that a lot too.

I don't know of a simple answer to your question I'm afraid. Other than doing some clever programming to monitor for file date changes and throwing up a warning dialog. I think that could be done with a PERSONAL.XLSM file and appropriate macro's.

UPDATE:

From the Stack Overflow question: [excel vba to reopen excel file without saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900495/excel-vba-to-reopen-excel-file-without-saving).

```
Sub ReOpen()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

You could put that into a personal macro workbook, assign it to a shortcut and/or custom ribbon entry. At least that lets you manually reload.

```
Application.OnTime
```

lets you run some code after a set period. See [VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon) for more details. Set a timer going when you load the workbook and it will reload every x seconds.

Comment: Actually, the author has locked the file with a password (to prevent unintentional edits) so I don't get the "Notify" option. I wonder if that's what's causing the problem?